# Is it safe to have two batteries in series on a solar panel system with 14.22v and 14.46v?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller, mppt

I have two batteries in series plugged to a solar panel system.

In parallel they used to balance each other perfectly.

But now i'm trying to have a 24v system and I have them in series.

They started both at a perfect 13.35v.

But just after plugging the MPPT, they don't keep the same voltage and i'm wondering what is the acceptable difference of voltage without being dangerous ? (considering i charge them at max 28.8v with an MPPT)

Now i have 14.22 and 14.46, so 0.24v difference. (they are same model Hankook DC24MF, lead acid sealed 80Ah but one is maybe 2 months older. - the 14.22v -)

(packaging is little different too, like stickers and informations layout.)

Comment: Note: the difference in voltage is not a problem for the batteries - **until** they get close to being fully charged (then one might be overcharged) or fully discharged (then one might be underdischarged).

Comment: Well my problem is that the solar charge controller is sending 28.8v anyway. If a battery fails, the rest of the voltage will be drawn to the other one, so heavy overcharging and explosion ? :-|

Comment: I suppose that's a possibility, but if one battery fails to 0V, you already have an explosion probably.

Comment: If a battery fails open circuit in a series circuit then the second battery won't be charged.

Comment: @SolarMike, oh really ? For me it's just a substration, the MPPT is sending 28.8v, if one battery can "take" only 10v, the other will jump to 28.8v - 10v = 18.8v and explode. Are you saying it is not how it works ? Thank you !!! :-)

Comment: @SolarMike I would love to have an expert opinion to make me feel better about this.